# Java Multi Threading writing and reading

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to know I am correct about the below code sample.
I have two Threads in java. `Thread_W and Thread_R`
**Both can access** the `Queue<String> queue`.

in Thread_W has a method called put.

```
private void put(String email){
 queue.offer(email);
}
```

And in the Thread_R there is a method called get AND it is once called when the Thread_R starts.

```
public void get(){
 while(true)
 {
   if(!queue.isEmpty())
   {
      String to = queue.poll();
      //thread will consume some time here ...may be 5-10 seconds.
   }
 }
}
```

so the method `put` in the Thread_W will called more efficiently by **A** other method in the Thread_W.may be in a while loop.

If I use this code in my Java project will the Thread_R lose any of the emails put into the queue?

P.S. I really need a Buffer

Comment: Look at java concurrency. You need a thread-safe queue.

Comment: why should the reading thread "lose any emails"?

Comment: You should use locking to prevent reading and writing from occurring at the same time.  The gist of it is write process is writing, so it locks down queue.  read process tries to access queue, but has to wait for write to be done..

Comment: U think not.me too.but like to have a look of a expert

Comment: You don't need locking if you use a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) such as [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) or [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html).

Comment: Ok tell me  Marshall Tigerus..if i use a lock .is the main thread of putting the values will hold ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a implementation of the [Blocking Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interface, as those are thread safe.

The interface offers the methods `put()` and `take()`, which block until they've executed. This way the reading thread doesn't consume a lot of CPU cycles and the writing thread doesn't write, if the queue is full.
Your current busy wait

```
while(true)
{
   if(!queue.isEmpty())
   {
       //...
   }
}
```

isn't very efficient. It is better to use a blocking method call, so you won't need to check, if the queue is empty (or full).
Also you can't overflow the queue's buffer, if your writing thread is way faster than the reading one as `put()` wait's [for space to become available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#put(E)).

Remember that you could always manually reserve a bigger buffer for the queue by setting the capicitiy in it's construtor beforehand, e.g. `ArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity)`.

Comment: But I need a big buffer size.unlimited.because the writing to the buffer will happen rapidly.only the reading will be slow

Comment: `put()` will block the writing thread, until there's space in the buffer. As per documentation: `Inserts the specified element into this queue, waiting if necessary for space to become available.` A bigger buffer wouldn't be the best solution.

Comment: put() will block the writing thread....it is the issue....
I need a buffer solution...like YouTube load all the video and then play

Comment: The wring thread writes in various speed.and the reading thread reads in another speed.
If the writer writes fast the value are loaded to a buffer then read one by one by the reader so no values are lost ..and there may be no value in the buffer ..when ever a new value is inserted to the buffer it is read by the reader

Comment: You could set the internal queue buffer as per my last edit, but you may need to rise the JVM's memory constraints then. Are you sure, you can't let the writing thread wait? Or use several reading threads?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an unbounded concurrent queue I would recommend taking a look at thread-safe implementations of `Deque`, for instance [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html). `LinkedBlockingDeque` can be unbounded and `take()` will block the calling thread if the queue is empty. You do not need to worry about synchronization if you use classes from the `java.util.concurent`package.